# SQL composite key value vs string

Tags: sql, primary-key, composite-primary-key

I have a list of integer from 1 to N elements (N < 24)

At the moment, there are two solutions to manage this value in a SQL database (I think it is the same for MySQL and Microsoft SQL Server)

**Solution 1**: use `VARCHAR` and `,` to separate integer values:

```
 aaa | 40,50,50,10,600,200
 aab | 40,50,600,200
 aac | 40,50,50,10,600,200,500,1
```

**Solution 2**: create a new table with composite primary key (key, id) (id = index of element in list) and value:

```
  aaa | 0 | 40
  aaa | 1 | 50
  aaa | 2 | 50
  ....
  aab | 0 | 40
  aab | 1 | 50
  aab | 2 | 600
  ....
```

What is it better solution considering I have many items of data to load and I need to refresh this data many times

Thanks

Edit: 
my operative case is: i need to refresh/read all data (list for key) with same call and i never call one by one, this is why i think first approach better.
And all math like avg or max i wanna do on client.

Comment: The second approach is correct.

Comment: ***NEVER EVER*** store more than one value into a single cell - it violates even the **first normal form** of relational database design and is a horribly bad way of storing data, which will come back to haunt you and cause you pain and headaches down the road - just **avoid this** at all costs!

Answer (score 2):

Usually the second approach is preferable. One advantage is ease of access:

```
-- Third value of aaa
select value from mytable where key = 'aaa' and pos = 3;

-- Avarage value of aaa
select avg(value) from mytable where key = 'aaa';

-- Avarage number of values
select avg(cnt) from (select count(*) as cnt from mytable group by key) counted;
```

Another is data consistency. You can add simple constraints to your columns, such as to allow only integers from, say, 1 to 700 and positions only up to 23.

There is an exception to the above, though. If you use the database only to store the list as is and you don't want to select separate values or even aggregate them, i.e. if this is just a string to the DBMS and your queries don't care about its content, then store it as a simple string. Why not?

Answer (score 1):

The second solution that you propose is the classic way of doing this, I would recommend that.

The first solution is quite terrible in scaling and in other hundred things